# Just created Azure Mobile App service calls return http 400 error

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Here's what I'm doing.

1. Install latest Azure SDK (by the date)
2. Open Visual Studio 2013
3. Create a new Azure Mobile App project. The simple service is created with TodoItem DataObject and 2 simple controllers - TodoItemController and ValuesController
4. Do not change anything
5. Start the project

The service is started and hosted in local IISExpress on url http://localhost:50993/  (the port may vary).
The *"This mobile app is up and running"* web page is opened in the browser. But http 400 error is returned when I try to invoke some GET-actions: for example *http://localhost:50993/api/values* or *http://localhost:50993/tables/TodoItem*.

Any ideas? Is something wrong in my environment or is that me doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual 400 error when you run this through Postman?  If you watch the debugging, then is anything printed?

Comment: My guess is that you have not added the X-ZUMO-VERSION header to the request though.  See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning/

Comment: @zhe did my answer below help ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can opt out of version checking by setting a value of true for the app setting MS_SkipVersionCheck. Specify this either in your web.config or in the Application Settings section of the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when you don't add a ZUMO-API-VERSION header to the request. This is required when making requests from a REST client, but the mobile client SDKs add the header automatically.

To fix, add the header `ZUMO-API-VERSION` with value of `2.0.0`. 
To learn more, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning/.

Answer (score -2):

Adding

```
http://localhost:50993/tables/Location?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
```

at the end will do the trick.